# PHP. Enter password to click button

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, passwords

So in my website is table which contains data from database. After button is clicked It truncate database table. I need to make that button will be click-able after password is entered. But I can't to It successfully.

Here are 2 fields "Username" and "Password". After button is clicked I don't get any errors It always truncate database. For this is needed to use (delete_table.php)

PHP

```
$username = $_POST['user'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
if ($username=="name1" || $username=="name2") {
    if ($password=="thepassword") {
        include("delete_table.php");
    } else {
        echo "Username or Password not entered correctly please try again.";
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<form method="post" action="delete_table.php" style="border:#000000 2px solid; width:375px;">
Username: 
<input type="text" name="user" size="35" />
<br />
Password:
<input type="password" name="password" size="35" /><br />
<input type="submit" id='delete' class='delete' name="delete" value='Išvalyti sąrašą'></input>
</center>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need Javascript for this because this is an clientside action:

```
<input type="password" name="password" size="35" id="password" /><br />
<input type="submit" id='delete' class='delete' disabled name="delete" value='Išvalyti sąrašą' />


document.getElementById('password').onkeyup = function(){
    document.getElementById('delete').disabled = false;
}
```

[And a jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RNjj9/)

---

I've added an id to the password so we can easily bind an event to it, the javascript code does that. I also added 'disabled' to the button, and in the eventfunction, I set that to false (so not-disabled->enabled).

Also, its not `<input></input>`, but `<input />`. Might be because you started with `<button>`, but worth a mentioning :)